# Xamarin.Android - adding versions to the layout designer

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, designer

Earlier today I had an issue where controls weren't rendering in the layout designer ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184379/xamarin-android-layout-designer-blank)) - I managed to fix this by setting the target framework of the app to 8.0 to match the version set at the top of the designer.

[image]

Problem is I need the target framework to be 9.0 and I only have 8.0 available in the designer. How do you add versions here? I have 9.0 installed in Tools/Android/Android SDK Manager/Platforms.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the [Visual Studio 2019 Preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/). We mention this functionality in the [Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview#constraint-layout)

Comment: Once you do that and have your `Target Framework Version` set to Pie (28), it should automatically use it.

Comment: I created a simple xamarin.android demo using version9.0 and it works all right. The problem is possibly related to the content of your layout. Would you please post your full layout xaml code so that we can test it for you

Comment: @JonDouglas - thank you! It works as expected in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @AbbyWang-MSFT - you can find my full layout code [here](https://pastebin.com/JxsJ5Zr2).